# Выровнять блоки по нижнему краю

Tags: css, css3, css-grid

Есть три блока в контейнере: http://prntscr.com/oj34tx

[image]

Нужно их выровнять по нижнему краю контейнера, без использования position:absolute. Кто-нибудь знает как? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как обычно flex + flex-end

```css
.items {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item1,
.item2,
.item3 {
  width: 200px;
}

.item1 {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 100px;
}

.item2 {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 130px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

.item3 {
  background: tomato;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item1"></div>
  <div class="item2"></div>
  <div class="item3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, выручил!